# Asp.Net MVC 5 route not hitting the controller while RouteDebugger says on the route true and Breakpoints are not hit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

**Hello,**
i'm having an issue where the route is correct when checking using Route Debugger and it says its true and working but the controller is not hit and the breakpoints on the code are not working while in starting controller they are working.

i'm using area in my project, and the project structure is:

area

---admin

--------controller

------------------AdminArticle

------------------AdminHome

---web

controller

----------Home

----------GFilesController

----------ArticleGFilesController

model

------Article

------Album

------etc

**my Route Code:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Falestinona2016V1
{

    public class RouteConfig {

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            //HttpMethodConstraint GetFileMethodConstraints = new HttpMethodConstraint(new string[] { "GET" });
            //Route GetFileRoute = new Route(
            //  url: "ArticleFilesManager/{UID}/{id}/{filename}",
            //  routeHandler: new DobImageRouteHandler(),
            //  defaults: null,
            //  constraints: new RouteValueDictionary { { "httpMethod", GetFileMethodConstraints } }
            //);
            //routes.Add("GetFileRoute", GetFileRoute);

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Delete File",
                url: "ArticleFilesManager/{UID}/{id}/{filename}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ArticleGFilesController", action = "Delete", area = "" },
                constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("DELETE") },
                namespaces: new[] { "Falestinona2016V1.Controllers" }
            ).DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Get Json File List ArticleFilesManager",
                url: "ArticleFilesManager/{UID}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ArticleGFilesController", action = "List", area = "", UID = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") },
                namespaces: new[] { "Falestinona2016V1.Controllers" }
            ).DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "PostArticleFilesUploadManager",
                url: "ArticleFilesManager/{UID}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ArticleGFilesController", action = "Uploads", area = "" },
                constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") },
                namespaces: new[] { "Falestinona2016V1.Controllers" }
            ).DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ArticleFilesUploadManager",
                url: "ArticleFilesManager/{UID}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ArticleGFilesController", area = "" },
                namespaces: new[] { "Falestinona2016V1.Controllers" }
            ).DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Falestinona2016V1.Controllers" }
            ).DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**My GFilesController:**

```
using Falestinona2016V1.GlobalObjects;
using Falestinona2016V1.GUtils;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Falestinona2016V1.Controllers {

    public class GFilesController : Controller {
        protected string storageRoot;

        public GFilesController() {
            storageRoot = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, AppSettings.GUploadsFolder);
        }

        public GFilesController(string subFolderCategory) : this() {
            storageRoot = Path.Combine(storageRoot, subFolderCategory + "\\");
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]
        public ActionResult Delete(string id, string filename) {
            if (id == null || filename == null) {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var filePath = Path.Combine(storageRoot, id + "-" + filename);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)) {
                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        public ActionResult Find(string id, string filename) {
            if (id == null || filename == null) {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var filePath = Path.Combine(storageRoot, id + "-" + filename);

            FileStreamResult result = new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open), GetMimeType(filePath));
            result.FileDownloadName = filename;

            return result;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public virtual ActionResult List() {
            var fileData = new List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(storageRoot);
            if (dir.Exists) {
                string[] extensions = MimeTypes.ImageMimeTypes.Keys.ToArray();

                FileInfo[] files = dir.EnumerateFiles()
                         .Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower()))
                         .ToArray();

                if (files.Length > 0) {
                    foreach (FileInfo file in files) {
                        var fileId = file.Name.Substring(0, 20);
                        var fileNameEncoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(file.Name.Substring(21));
                        var relativePath = "/FilesUploading/" + fileId + "-" + fileNameEncoded;

                        fileData.Add(new ViewDataUploadFilesResult() {
                            url = relativePath,
                            thumbnail_url = relativePath, //@"data:image/png;base64," + EncodeFile(fullName),
                            name = fileNameEncoded,
                            type = MimeTypes.ImageMimeTypes[file.Extension],
                            size = Convert.ToInt32(file.Length),
                            delete_url = relativePath,
                            delete_type = "DELETE"
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

            var result = new ContentResult {
                Content = "{\"files\":" + serializer.Serialize(fileData) + "}",
            };
            return result;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Uploads() {
            var fileData = new List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();

            foreach (string file in Request.Files) {
                UploadWholeFile(Request, fileData);
            }

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

            var result = new ContentResult {
                Content = "{\"files\":" + serializer.Serialize(fileData) + "}",
            };
            return result;
        }

        protected virtual void UploadWholeFile(HttpRequestBase request, List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult> statuses) {
            for (int i = 0; i < request.Files.Count; i++) {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = request.Files[i];

                var fileId = IDGen.NewID();
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var fileNameEncoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(fileName);
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(storageRoot, fileId + "-" + fileName);

                file.SaveAs(fullPath);

                statuses.Add(new ViewDataUploadFilesResult() {
                    url = "/Files/" + fileId + "-" + fileNameEncoded,
                    thumbnail_url = "/Files/" + fileId + "-" + fileNameEncoded, //@"data:image/png;base64," + EncodeFile(fullName),
                    name = fileNameEncoded,
                    type = file.ContentType,
                    size = file.ContentLength,
                    delete_url = "/Files/" + fileId + "-" + fileNameEncoded,
                    delete_type = "DELETE"
                });
            }
        }

        private string EncodeFile(string fileName) {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
        }

        private string GetMimeType(string filePath) {
            return GetMimeType(new FileInfo(filePath));
        }

        private string GetMimeType(FileInfo file) {
            return MimeTypes.ImageMimeTypes[file.Extension];
        }
    }
}
```

**My ArticleGFilesController:**

```
using Falestinona2016V1.GUtils;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Falestinona2016V1.Controllers {

    public class ArticleGFilesController : GFilesController {
        private string uid;

        public ArticleGFilesController() : base("Articles") {
            Guid tempGUID;
            if (Guid.TryParse(RouteData.Values["UID"] as string, out tempGUID)) {
                uid = tempGUID.ToString();
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public override ActionResult List() {
            return Content("Test");
            try {
                var fileData = new List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();

                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(storageRoot, uid + "\\"));
                if (dir.Exists) {
                    string[] extensions = MimeTypes.ImageMimeTypes.Keys.ToArray();

                    FileInfo[] files = dir.EnumerateFiles()
                             .Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower()))
                             .ToArray();

                    if (files.Length > 0) {
                        foreach (FileInfo file in files) {
                            var fileId = file.Name.Substring(0, 20);
                            var fileNameEncoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(file.Name.Substring(21));
                            //var relativePath = "/FilesUploading/" + fileId + "-" + fileNameEncoded;
                            var relativePath = string.Format("/ArticleFilesManager/{0}/{1}-{2}", uid, fileId, fileNameEncoded);

                            fileData.Add(new ViewDataUploadFilesResult() {
                                url = relativePath,
                                thumbnail_url = relativePath, //@"data:image/png;base64," + EncodeFile(fullName),
                                name = fileNameEncoded,
                                type = MimeTypes.ImageMimeTypes[file.Extension],
                                size = Convert.ToInt32(file.Length),
                                delete_url = relativePath,
                                delete_type = "DELETE"
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

                var result = new ContentResult {
                    Content = "{\"files\":" + serializer.Serialize(fileData) + "}",
                };
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                return Content(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        protected override void UploadWholeFile(HttpRequestBase request, List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult> statuses) {
            for (int i = 0; i < request.Files.Count; i++) {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = request.Files[i];

                var fileId = IDGen.NewID();
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var fileNameEncoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(fileName);
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(storageRoot, uid, fileId + "-" + fileName);

                file.SaveAs(fullPath);

                statuses.Add(new ViewDataUploadFilesResult() {
                    //url = "/Files/" + fileId + "-" + fileNameEncoded,
                    url = string.Format("/ArticleFilesManager/{0}/{1}-{2}", uid, fileId, fileNameEncoded),
                    thumbnail_url = string.Format("/ArticleFilesManager/{0}/{1}-{2}", uid, fileId, fileNameEncoded), //@"data:image/png;base64," + EncodeFile(fullName),
                    name = fileNameEncoded,
                    type = file.ContentType,
                    size = file.ContentLength,
                    delete_url = string.Format("/ArticleFilesManager/{0}/{1}-{2}", uid, fileId, fileNameEncoded),
                    delete_type = "DELETE"
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My HomeController:**

```
using Falestinona2016V1.Areas.Admin;
using Falestinona2016V1.GlobalObjects;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Falestinona2016V1.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : GController {

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminHome", new { area = new AdminAreaRegistration().AreaName });
        }
    }
}
```

My **Area --> Admin --> Controllers --> AdminHomeController**

```
using Falestinona2016V1.Areas.Admin.AdminGlobalObjects;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Falestinona2016V1.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{

    public class AdminHomeController : AdminGController {

        // GET: Admin/AdminHome
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

while i'm in the url:
domain/admin/adminhome

i'm trying to enter the url: domain/ArticleFilesManager/fdghdfhgdfjgkjdfg
but the ArticleGFilesController --> list action is not hit
while using also: domain/ArticleFilesManager/c7db4817-c4f5-41c9-ae5c-d12d2d2a2f1c

i'm unable to figure out the issue, while route debugger:

[Route Debugger Results Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkI6w.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks to "rymling",** the solution is:
Remove the Controller part from the controller name:

```
defaults: new { controller = "ArticleGFiles",
```